# How to rewrite query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update based on a select. The following errors with: `the column '' was specified multiple times for Q`

```
UPDATE Evolution1.DimAdministrator 
SET  Evolution1.DimAdministrator.ClaimSystemCodeId = 17 
FROM Evolution1.DimAdministrator da  INNER JOIN (
    Select
        ExtractId,   
        base.AdministratorId, 
        base.CardprocessorAdministratorId, 
        AdministratorName,                                 
        EffectiveDate,           
        CancelDate ,             
        State,
        StageError  ,
        AdministratorKey,
        CustomerKey ,
        Name            ,                                                                                     
        EffectiveDateKey ,
        CancelDateKey,
        StateProvinceKey ,
        Alias ,
        NavId     ,  
        warehouse.AdministratorId ,
        warehouse.CardprocessorAdministratorId,
        warehouse.ClaimSystemCodeId, 
        Inserted ,               
        Updated
    FROM OneStage.OnePay.Administrator base
    INNER JOIN OneWarehouse.Evolution1.DimAdministrator warehouse ON base.AdministratorId = warehouse.AdministratorId
    WHERE base.ClaimSystemCodeId <> warehouse.ClaimSystemCodeId
    AND base.ClaimSystemCodeId = 1
) AS Q
```

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: So which is it, SQL Server, Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Syntax seems specific to MSSQL.
Proposed an edit.

Comment: Join On condition is missing.     ) AS Q
ON Q.<<Column>>= da.<<Column>> . Also in your subquery there is no need for warehouse.AdministratorId as it is same as base.AdministratorId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple columns with duplicate names.

Put an alias on them like this:

```
UPDATE Evolution1.DimAdministrator 
SET  Evolution1.DimAdministrator.ClaimSystemCodeId = 17 
FROM Evolution1.DimAdministrator da  INNER JOIN (
    Select
        ExtractId,   
        base.AdministratorId AS base_AdminID, 
        base.CardprocessorAdministratorId AS base_CardID, 
        AdministratorName,                                 
        EffectiveDate,           
        CancelDate ,             
        State,
        StageError  ,
        AdministratorKey,
        CustomerKey ,
        Name            ,                                                                                     
        EffectiveDateKey ,
        CancelDateKey,
        StateProvinceKey ,
        Alias ,
        NavId     ,  
        warehouse.AdministratorId wh_AdminID,
        warehouse.CardprocessorAdministratorId AS WH_CardID,
        warehouse.ClaimSystemCodeId, 
        Inserted ,               
        Updated
    FROM OneStage.OnePay.Administrator base
    INNER JOIN OneWarehouse.Evolution1.DimAdministrator warehouse ON base.AdministratorId = warehouse.AdministratorId
    WHERE base.ClaimSystemCodeId <> warehouse.ClaimSystemCodeId
    AND base.ClaimSystemCodeId = 1
) AS Q
```

Are you sure you don't need to JOIN Q **ON** something?